# pivoting from comma delimited column value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to work on  old poorly design database

It has table like below

```
CREATE TABLE answers (ID INT, ans NVARCHAR(300))
INSERT INTO answers VALUES 
(1,'a,b,a,c,d,b,x,x,y'),
(2,'b,b,a,c,d,d,x,x,y'),
(3, 'p,q,r,s,p,q')
```

I need to have result like below

```
id   a   b  c   d  e
1    2   2  1   1  0
```

what could be the best way?

columns are from a to z

Comment: you don't do it in sql. it is UGLY to take a single field's value and split into actual NEW fields, especially when the number of "new" fields is arbitrary and varies. Suck the `ans` field into your client app and do the splitting up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the specific letters on each row.  This is possible:

```
select id,
       (len(ans) - len(replace(ans, 'a', ''))) as a,
       (len(ans) - len(replace(ans, 'b', ''))) as b,
       (len(ans) - len(replace(ans, 'c', ''))) as c,
       (len(ans) - len(replace(ans, 'd', ''))) as d,
       (len(ans) - len(replace(ans, 'e', ''))) as e
from answers;
```

The count is calculated by taking the length of the `ans` column and then subtracting the length when each letter is removed.

Comment: YOU ARE KING OF SQL, HATSOFF TO YOU